# Windows 8 keyboard in Mac VMWare types incorrect symbols

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, vmware-fusion

I am running Windows 8 inside VMWare Fusion (Professional Version 5.0.4 (1435862)) in a Mac. When I type a symbol, I get a different one. The keyboard used in Windows 8 is UK English.

```
Shift + 2, I get " instead of @
Shift + 3, I get £ instead of  #
Shift + ', I get @ instead of double quote
When I press \, I get #
When I press Shift + \, I get ~ (instead of pipe)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: What keyboard is Windows 8 set to use?  What version of VMWare Fusion are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound Updated details in question

Comment: I assume you have installed the current VMWare Tools within the guest operating system?  Do you actually have a UK keyboard?

Comment: I have a regular Mac Keyboard. whats different in a UK keyboard?

Comment: While I am looking at a non-Apple keyboard I don't see how Shift+/ would result in `|`( I believe that to be pipe ) nor `~` to be honest even looking at the default US Apple keyboard layout http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2841.  The first thing I would change is the Windows 8 keyboard layout to something other then UK English.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing the keyboard to 'US International' whilst leaving the language as English UK

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in this case between the setup in your VM and on real hardware. The keyboard does not send and <kbd>@</kbd> or an <kbd>"</kbd>. It sends a code. Some thing like 'key number 55 was pressed'.

It is up to the OS to decide which letter or symbol to match up to that.

For UK English the keycode matching "shift-2" is matched to an @.
For UK English the keycode matching "shift-3" is matched to an £.

For US-international the the keycode matching "shift-2" is matched to an ".
  For US-international the the keycode matching "shift-3" is matched to an #.

So things are working perfectly as designed and as configured. If you want other functionality. If you want proper English<sup>*</sup> but a normal keyboard then you select that in regional settings. Windows will *helpfully* try to suggest a UK keyboard layout. You need to manually fix this so it matches your real keyboard.

This is a know issue which and causes problems in many languages which a special keyboard exists for that country, but where they are never (or rarely) used.

---

<sup>*</sup>: Snobbish for the Queens language, and not simplified english.